# PHP: Маска элементов в массиве

Tags: php, ооп, маршрутизация

изучаю то как работают фраймворки
И решил сделать свою систему роутов
Сейчас у меня работает так

```
$route->addRoute({method}, "{route}", {controller function or object})
```

Пример

```
$route->addRoute(POST, "/blog", [\Controllers\BlogController::class, "showPage"])
```

В классе route я просто записываю обработчик и роут в массив
А потом при обращении смотрю в массиве какой обработчик под этим роутом
[image: addRoute]

И при подключении ищу роут:
[image]

Как сделать передачу параметров? Например вот так

```
$route->addRoute(POST, "/hello/{id}", function($response, $request, ...$params){
    return $response->setBody("Id: " . $params['id']);
});
```

Переменная $response хранит объект для формирования ответа, $request не важно
Как можно сделать $params?
Пробовал формировать регулярные выражения при добавлении роута в массив, а потом через foreach сравнивать, но это не поддерживает большое количество параметров

Comment: на чем споткнулись с регулярками? в целом можно преобразовать параметры в именованные группы регулярки. так же в целом пометить маршрут как параметризованный, и сделать шаблон регулярки, применяемый по умолчанию, если маска не задана в параметрах роута

Comment: по структуре хранения в в массиве `routes['get/post']`, имеет смысл навернео раздлеить на статически роуты и параметризованные. а внутри уже сохранять данные о тип. В целом один маршрут может обрабатывать запрос разного типа в т.ч. и реагировать на оба одновременно. у вас сейчас всегда один вариант. и в целом, странно, что при задани роутов вы юзаете константу POST, а в коде обработки констант никаких  нет.

Comment: Я для примера написал константу, у меня немного по-другому